# Vimscript check if current buffer has unsaved changes

Tags: vim

I currently have my status line set up so that it's orange in insert mode and white otherwise. I'd like to make it go another color when I drop back to normal mode if the file has any unsaved changes, as I regularly take a little walk down a rabbit hole wondering why my changes have not taken effect. The little "[+]" doesn't smack me in the face enough ;)

I can't find any functions that start with "buf" and look like predicates for dirtiness though. I assume one exists, but is named something else. I expect there to be something like `bufdirty()` or `bufchanged()`. Any pointers? :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think that you are looking for

```
:echo &mod[ified]
```

which returns `1` if modified and `0` if not modified.

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of using the statusline color to indicate the buffer state. In fact, I've written the [StatusLineHighlight plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3383), which indicates the following attributes: modified, readonly, unmodifiable, special non-file "scratch" (but not the insert mode that you're using; for that, I find Vim's mode indication in the lower left corner enough).

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look at your plugin and may use it if it is unobtrusive enough :)

Comment: Using your plugin, thanks. Changed all the colors so only a few modes look different, but it works well. Maybe you can consider add StatusLineInsert to the list (then I could consolidate my own autocmd!) ;)

Comment: Actually, stopped using it as I couldn't quite get the behaviour I wanted with insert mode (and oddly, the foreground/background colors reversed when reloading .vimrc). I did steal your wisdom with regard to the events to use though, thanks! ;) https://github.com/d11wtq/dot-vim/blob/master/vimrc#L161-178