# Key mapping confusion in VIM,How to make vim works in a smart way?

Tags: vim, mapping, key, confirmation

I want to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> with `:q` command in vim That is to say, I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> to close the current window of vim,

So I add this to my `~/.vimrc` :

```
nmap <C-W> :q<cr>
```

When I use this to close a window that has something unsaved,this command cannot work.

So I want to make it works in a smart way: When the content is saved, just close the window. When the content remains unsaved, ask me whether to close the window directly like this command

```
:0,$s/a/b/gc
```

I don't know if this is clear enough for you, but thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, I would *strongly* recommend picking something other than c-w, as c-w is the prefix used for window operations, which are really, really useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I know ,and I use some other key to manage window operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the `:confirm` command for that. Just put it in front of `:quit`:

```
:nmap <C-W> :confirm q<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to `set confirm` in your `vimrc` - this will prompt you before closing without saving (and a few other things, too; see `:help confirm`).

Otherwise, you could write a little vim script which uses [`&modified`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107453/vimscript-check-if-current-buffer-has-unsaved-changes) and `confirm()` (see `:help confirm()`).